# Laravel mix build stopped after a time and very slow

Tags: laravel, performance, vue.js, npm, laravel-mix

I have an application built with Laravel 8 and Vue 3 (in the same project) which is running with laravel mix. I am running the app with docker with different containers.

Laravel part is running, but the issue is with frontend part. I run "npm run dev" on node container to start the laravel mix that build the application. For some reasons, the process is stopped at 15% (not on the same file) without any error. I don't know why.

It seems to be a timeout value on running commands or maybe a bad config.

This is my webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
const path = require("path");

mix.ts("resources/ts/app.ts", "public/js")
    .vue({ version: 3 })
    .webpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /.mjs$/i,
                    resolve: {
                        byDependency: { esm: { fullySpecified: false } },
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/ts/src/"),
            },
        },
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the standard output of your terminal depicting the process stoppage at 15%.

Comment: What does "*not on the same file*" mean?

Comment: https://snipboard.io/DFClp0.jpg

Comment: I mean that the file where the process is stopped is not the same (so in this case is not an issue on a file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. It was a memory issue. So, I increased memory on my server and build is complete now.

Comment: try building it locally, why not?

Comment: Could you please share how you fixed this? I'm running into the exact same problem with the exact same code and I have no clue on what to do

Comment: Increase the memory if you are using docker.

Comment: @Adrian Is that all you did? I'm using Laravel Sail on WSL2 for Windows, and I tried increasing the memory, but it still did not work